# Tagged Text in Android EditView

Tags: android, android-layout, tags, editview

I would like to achieve an edit view that tags the text after a user has entered some text (in my case a phonenumber) and the user presses a comma. So for input that has `Trevor Hansen, Alex Nelson, ...` the output will be like this:

[image: Courtesy: Google Material: Color Schemes]

Answer (score 2):

Check out below library that serves what you want

[Android chips with AutoComplete](https://github.com/klinker41/android-chips)

Happy Coding! :)

Comment: nice answer +1, exactly is the same :)

Comment: @falcon if it helps kindly mark this as answer so that it can be helpful to others as well.

Comment: @ShrenikShah thank you! Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can use these libraries:

[AndroidTagView](https://github.com/whilu/AndroidTagView)

[EditTag](https://github.com/qiugang/EditTag)

[TagsEditText](https://github.com/mabbas007/TagsEditText)

Answer (score 0):

Go through the below code, add a TextWatcher and your logic:

```
phoneNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.phone);
tag = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tag);

phoneNumber.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

        String mobNo = editable.toString();

        if (mobNo != null && mobNo.length() >= 1) {

            if (mobNo.contains(",")) {
                mob = new SpannableString(mobNo.replace(",", ""));
                tag.setText(mob);
                phoneNumber.setText("");
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Add your logic for multiple data persistence.